# UIView background color not changing

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, background-color, uicolor

I am declaring several UIViews that are added to my UIScroll view in a for loop, I would like to know how to change the color of each UIView background when the loop progresses. Currently each UIVIew just stays the same color grey.

This is what my code looks like:

```
UIScrollView *htmlContainerScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 60.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 293.0)];
    NSInteger viewcount = 4;
    color = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< viewcount; i++) {
        color = color + 4;
        NSLog(@"%f", color);
        CGFloat y = i * self.view.frame.size.height;
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y,self.view.frame.size.width, self .view.frame.size.height)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(200.0 + i)/255.0 green:(200.0 + i)/255.0 blue:(200.0 + i)/255.0 alpha:1.0];;
        [htmlContainerScrollView addSubview:view];

    }
```

Comment: what's the height of your "`self.view.frame.size.height`"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(200.0 + i)/255.0 green:(200.0 + i)/255.0 blue:(200.0 + i)/255.0 alpha:1.0];;
```

Whenever Red, Green, and Blue has the same value, the color is gray.

Add constant value different then 200 to, at least, Red component and you'll see different colors.

Comment: Hrmm.. I just tried this and the color changed to the last value for each of the views created....

Comment: a combination of the two answers worked. however yours was the most effective in achiving my outcome.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your adding "i" instead of "color" when you try to change your colors, so your only adding 1, 2, 3, and 4 to your 200 which won't be noticeable. You might try using a larger number than 4 when you increment color as well.

Comment: cant belive i missed that. thanks very much ... it works now.